# Android accessibility permissions turn off after device restart

Tags: android, permissions, accessibility, android-permissions, application-settings

I have a android radio installed in my car. Every time i turn on the radio the accessibility permissions are no longer "on" (but all data remains on the device). (android 11). It happens with the app macrodroid, but i think that the problem isn't the app itself...

I saw that the battery optimizations is not activated for the specific app. Someone knows what to do?